# Creating LinFu interceptors for all types within an assembly

Tags: c#, aop, linfu

I'm trying to create LinFu interceptors for all methods in my DAL assembly. While I can do something like this:

```
[Intercepts(typeof(IFirstRepository))]
[Intercepts(typeof(ISecondaryRepository))]
[Intercepts(typeof(IIAnotherRepository))]
public class DalInterceptor : IInterceptor, IInitialize
{
... 
}
```

that's getting quite messy and needs manual updating every time a new repository is added to the assembly.

Is there a way to automatically create a proxy class for each type in the assembly?

UPDATE:

I've updated my proxy builder using the suggestion from the author himself (Mr Laureano) so I now have this:

```
Func<IServiceRequestResult, object> createProxy = request =>
{
    var proxyFactory = new ProxyFactory();
    DalInterceptor dalInterceptor = new DalLiteInterceptor();
    return proxyFactory.CreateProxy<object>(dalInterceptor);
};
```

The interceptor is set up as before. The issue I'm having now is that the proxy object doesn't include the constructors and methods of the original object (I'm guessing as I'm using object in the generic create method).

Do I just cast this back to the required type or am I doing something fundamentally wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you heard of PostSharp? It allows you way more expressiveness than what you are doing with LinFu.

Comment: We're using LinFu mainly as an IoC container. The aspects stuff is just really to add tracing while debugging. We're quite entrenched in using LinFu bow but I'll keep PostSharp in mind to try in future. Thanks.

Comment: You have to cast it to the required service type since the container expects an instance of the service type itself, and not a System.Object. All you have to do is create a proxy using the service type and you should be all set to go

Comment: Sorry for the delay in replying; I didn't realise there had been another message posted. I'm having some trouble working out where to cast the object created. I can get the requested type from request.ServiceType but I can't use this in the generic proxyFactory.CreateProxy<T> method unless there's a way to include this type somewhere that I don't know of. For instance, I can't do something like proxyFactory.CreateProxy<request.ServiceType.GetType()>.

Comment: LinFu's ProxyFactory class has a non-generic overload for CreateProxy that takes the type you want to intercept. If you have any other questions, just email it to marttub (atsign) hotmail dot com and I can give you better examples there. HTH :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to use LinFu's IOC container to intercept various services that are instantiated by the container. It turns out that LinFu has an internal class called ProxyInjector that lets you decide which services should be intercepted and how the proxy for each service instance should be created. Here's the sample code:

```
Func<IServiceRequestResult, bool> shouldInterceptServiceInstance = request=>request.ServiceType.Name.EndsWith("Repository");

Func<IServiceRequestResult, object> createProxy = request =>
{
   // TODO: create your proxy instance here
   return yourProxy;
};

// Create the injector and attach it to the container so that you can selectively
// decide which instances should be proxied
var container = new ServiceContainer();
var injector = new ProxyInjector(shouldInterceptServiceInstance, createProxy);
container.PostProcessors.Add(injector);

// ...Do something with the container here
```

EDIT: I just modified the ProxyInjector class so that it is now a public class instead of an internal class in LinFu. Try it out and let me know if that helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks for getting back to me. I've pulled down the latest from GitHub, just trying to work out what I'm using. I've just been using the Core assembly up till now but the build script has created a lot of different assemblies. Just piecing together what I need now then I'll try out that code.

Comment: If you have ILMerge installed, you can type "go merge" at the command line and it should give you a single assembly with all the dependencies you need. HTH :)

Comment: Managed to get LinFu building (seems I was missing ILMerge). Need to add code so have edited original question with updated code.